# Does Leiningen read maven settings in .m2/settings.xml?

Tags: maven, clojure, leiningen

I have several additional repositories in `~/.m2/settings.xml`. I tried `lein search` and it doesn't find the packages in my repositories. How can I tell leiningen to search repositories in maven settings?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can add the `:repositories` tag to your project.clj file:

```
(defproject com.foo/bar "1.0.0-SNAPSHOT"
  ;; ...other configuration...
  :repositories [["java.net" "http://download.java.net/maven/2"]])
```

Take a look at the official [sample project.clj](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj).

You'll have to copy over the repository configuration from your settings.xml file, but this is the idiomatic and recommended way to manage repositories with Leiningen.

[Does lein2 use repositories defined in ~/.m2/settings.xml?](http://grokbase.com/p/gg/clojure/132n4ptwdm/does-lein2-use-repositories-defined-in-m2-settings-xml)

Answer (score 4):

BTW, if you really want to add Maven repositories or mirrors on user profile level (useful for internal company proxy repositories like Nexus, especially if Lein has its [usual problems with corporate NTLM proxies](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/wiki/HTTP-Proxies#ntml-proxies)), then you can do this in `~/.lein/profiles.clj` / `%USERPROFILE%\.lein\profiles.clj`:

[How to configure leiningen's maven usage?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16481227/how-to-configure-leiningens-maven-usage)

In my case, on Windows, it was sufficient to place this `:mirrors` map in my `%USERPROFILE%\.lein\profiles.clj`:

```
{:user
    {
        :java-cmd "C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_09\\bin\\java.exe"
            :plugins [    ]
            :mirrors {
                #".+"  "http://internal-nexus.example.com/content/groups/public-all/"
            }
    }
}
```

`

The `#".+"` specifies the name of mirrored repository using pattern syntax that matches all possible names (resulting in mirroring every repository), as described in this [Leiningen issue report 271](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/271).