# Using a mirror of Clojars from Leiningen

Tags: clojure, leiningen

The following Wiki page describes a straightforward way of setting up Leiningen to use a mirror of Clojars.org: https://github.com/clojars/clojars-web/wiki/Mirrors

Based on this, I have put the following as my `~/.lein/profiles.clj`:

```
{:user {:mirrors 
        {#"clojars" {:name "clojars mirror" 
                     :url "https://clojars-mirror.tcrawley.org/repo/"}}}}
```

However, even with this `profiles.clj`, I can still see in e.g. Wireshark that `lein` is trying to connect to `clojars.org` instead of `clojars-mirror.tcrawley.org`. What setting am I missing?

My Leiningen version is

> Leiningen 2.5.3 on Java 1.7.0_91 OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM

Comment: When looking with wireshark, can you tell what URI it is trying to fetch?

Comment: @tobycrawley not really, because it's using HTTPS.

Comment: Ah, right - you would just see it trying to establish the initial connection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I couldn't get a mirror working by modifying `profile.clj` either.

However I was able to get it working for a specific `project.clj` by adding this within `defproject`

```
  :mirrors {#"clojars" {:name "Clojar Mirror"
                    :url "https://clojars-mirror.tcrawley.org/repo/"
                    :repo-manager true}}
```

**Notes:**

This came from the official Leiningen sample `project.clj`:

- https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/blob/master/sample.project.clj

I tried following the below for global setting in `profile.clj` (the syntax is somewhat different from yours) but had no luck:

- https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen/issues/271#issuecomment-21108691
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/17697119/617320

Comment: Bonus question: how would I use this if I needed to download a `lein` plugin from the mirror that is needed to create a new project in the first place?

Comment: Maybe add the plugin to an existing project, run `lein deps` to pull it into `~/.m2`, then add it to your new project and use the `lein -o` (offline) flag.